Minimal reproducible example package using Rcpp does not work
In short: I tried with SO and chatGPT, at some point I thought the NAMESPACE file was the error and deleted it. However, I still get an error when I run
Rcpp::compileAttributes(pkgdir = "path2package/testRcpp/", verbose = TRUE)

Error:
Error in Rcpp::compileAttributes(pkgdir = "path2package/testRcpp/",  :
pkgdir must refer to the directory containing an R package

I also created a new identical package from the scratch and build it:
Rcpp::compileAttributes(verbose = TRUE)
Exports from path2package/testRcpp2/src/CppFunctions.cpp:
   double meanC(NumericVector x)

keine nativen Symbole extrahiert
path2package/testRcpp2/src/RcppExports.cpp updated.
path2package/testRcpp2/R/RcppExports.R updated.

and used
devtools::document()
ℹ Updating testRcpp2 documentation
First time using roxygen2. Upgrading automatically...
Setting `RoxygenNote` to "7.2.3"
ℹ Loading testRcpp2
Exports from path2package/testRcpp2/src/CppFunctions.cpp:
   double meanC(NumericVector x)

keine nativen Symbole extrahiert
path2package/testRcpp2/src/RcppExports.cpp updated.
path2package/testRcpp2/R/RcppExports.R updated.
ℹ Re-compiling testRcpp2 (debug build)
── R CMD INSTALL ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─  installing *source* package 'testRcpp2' ... (356ms)
   ** using staged installation
   ** libs
   g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/R/R-4.2.2/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/R/R-4.2.2/library/Rcpp/include'   -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall -gdwarf-2 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -UNDEBUG -Wall -pedantic -g -O0 -fdiagnostics-color=always -c CppFunctions.cpp -o CppFunctions.o
   g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/R/R-4.2.2/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/R/R-4.2.2/library/Rcpp/include'   -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall -gdwarf-2 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -UNDEBUG -Wall -pedantic -g -O0 -fdiagnostics-color=always -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
   g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -static-libgcc -o testRcpp2.dll tmp.def CppFunctions.o RcppExports.o -LC:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64 -LC:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib -LC:/R/R-4.2.2/bin/x64 -lR
   installing to C:/Users/CHRIST~1.STR/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpojw9xx/devtools_install_45bc13bd1b7f/00LOCK-testRcpp2/00new/testRcpp2/libs/x64
─  DONE (testRcpp2)
Writing meanC.Rd
Warning messages:
1: Skipping NAMESPACE
✖ It already exists and was not generated by roxygen2. 
2: Skipping NAMESPACE
✖ It already exists and was not generated by roxygen2. 

Restarting R session...

So eveything looks fine. But
testRcpp2::meanC(c(1, 2, 3))
Error in .Call("_testRcpp_meanC", PACKAGE = "testRcpp", x) : 
  "_testRcpp_meanC" not available for .Call() for package "testRcpp"

After deleting the NAMESPACE everything is screwed up again :-(
Any help is highly appreciated!

Details:
I have a package in "path2package/testRcpp" with the following structure
testRcpp/
├── DESCRIPTION
├── R/
│   └── functions.R
├── src/
│   └── CppFunctions.cpp
└── man/

with
dir.exists("path2package/testRcpp/")
# [1] TRUE
file.exists("path2package/testRcpp/DESCRIPTION")
# [1] TRUE

and
list.files(all.files = TRUE)
 [1] "."  ".." ".git" ".gitignore" ".Rbuildignore" 
 [6] ".Rhistory" ".Rproj.user" "DESCRIPTION" "man" "R" 
[11] "src" "testRcpp.Rproj" "tests"       

I have a file src/CppFunctions.cpp with content
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double meanC(NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  double total = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    total += x[i];
  }
  return total / n;
}

and a file R/functions.R with content
#' @useDynLib mypackage
#' @importFrom Rcpp sourceCpp
NULL

# Example function documentation

#' Calculate the mean using a C++ function
#'
#' @param x A numeric vector
#' @return A numeric, the mean of the vector
#' @export
meanC <- function(x) {
  .Call('_testRcpp_meanC', PACKAGE = 'testRcpp', x)
}

The DESCRIPTION file contains
Package: testRcpp
Type: Package
Title: What the Package Does (Title Case)
Version: 0.1.0
Author: Who wrote it
Maintainer: The package maintainer <yourself@somewhere.net>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
    Use four spaces when indenting paragraphs within the Description.
License: What license is it under?
Encoding: UTF-8
Depends: R (>= 3.5.0)
Imports: Rcpp (>= 1.0.5)
LinkingTo: Rcpp
LazyData: true
Suggests: 
    testthat (>= 3.0.0)
Config/testthat/edition: 3
RoxygenNote: 7.2.3

I deleted the NAMESPACE file, because I thought this could be the error...
Now, if I run
Rcpp::compileAttributes(pkgdir = "path2package/testRcpp/", verbose = TRUE)

I get the error

Error in Rcpp::compileAttributes(pkgdir = "path2package/testRcpp/",  :
pkgdir must refer to the directory containing an R package


What happens when you a) create a working default package via e.g. Rcpp.package.skeleton("mypkg") and then b) do setwd("mypkg"); compileAttributes(".") ?

@AdaLovelace: Does not work - I guess I miss some steps? How would you do it step by step? I have to look tomorrow :-(

Does Rcpp::evalCpp("21 + 21") work?

@AdaLovelace It's really strange, I can build the package, but when I call testRcpp3::meanC(c(1, 2, 3)) it says Error in .Call("_testRcpp_meanC", PACKAGE = "testRcpp", x) :
"_testRcpp_meanC" not available for .Call() for package "testRcpp". And the NAMESPACE contains useDynLib(testRcpp3, .registration=TRUE); importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp); exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+") which looks wrong.

When I further run Rcpp::compileAttributes(verbose = TRUE) everything seems OK: Exports from pathto/testRcpp3/src/CppFunctions.cpp: double meanC(NumericVector x)
Exports from pathto/testRcpp3/src/rcpp_hello_world.cpp: List rcpp_hello_world() keine nativen Symbole extrahiert pathto/testRcpp3/R/RcppExports.R updated.
But NAMESPACE does not change...

@AdaLovelace So perhaps the real question is, why does Rcpp::compileAttributes() not change the NAMESPACE?

Are you sure the documentation states it would do that?  I always used either a global export in NAMESPACE or explicit tags and roxygen2.

@AdaLovelace To be honest, I am not sure - I am more mathematician than software engineer. I still learn after almost 10 years ;-) What would you recommend? See also my other question here...

My recommendation would be to read to Rcpp documentation slowly and carefully and minimize what you are doing. If things do not work with RStudio and devtools and whatnot, do not use. Fall back to R CMD build ... and R CMD INSTALL ... as a test. These always work for me.  Once you have that work add other convenience layers. As for your NAMESPACE question, I think you are just confused and I do not think Rcpp::compilerAttributes() ever touched that file. roxygen2 on the other hand does so it can be a two-step: First compileAttributes(), then roxygenize() with proper tags.
